# Inflate dynamic layout for displaying questionnaire from JSON

Tags: android, retrofit

How to inflate dynamic layout for displaying questionnaire from JSON using Retrofit?

I am getting list of questions from web service and I need to display it in UI dynamically

Comment: Please explain what response you get and what  UI you are using so we can understand your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To inflate a layout dynamically use [`getLayoutInflater().inflate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup)).

This will return a `View` object which you can add to an existing layout (`ViewGroup`) by calling `addView()`.

Comment: Thank you @Minas Mina, this answer was helpful !!

Comment: @GarrimaKakkr I'm glad :) Could you accept the answer? Thanks!